# rxjs subscription returning duplicates

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, google-cloud-datastore

After making a subscription from Angular service, the returning results are bunch of duplicates. For every call, the number of duplicates increase by one.

I tried console logging the results at various stages of the app. The duplicates are returned immediately after the promise get rendered

Angular Service code:

```
GetUserPendingApprovals(userid: string) {
    let approvalsPending: any[] = [];
    this.http
      .get<{message, approvals: any}>(`/api/approvals/${userid}`)
        .subscribe(approvals => {
          console.log(approvals.approvals);
          approvalsPending = approvals.approvals;
          this.approvalsUpdated.next(approvalsPending);
          approvalsPending = [];
      });
  }
getUserPendingApprovalsUpdateListener() {
  return this.approvalsUpdated.asObservable();
}
```

node end point:

```
app.get("/api/approvals/:userid", (req, res, next) => {
  // const urlData = req.params.userId;
  //console.log(urlData);
  const query = datastore
  .createQuery('approvals')
  .filter('src', '=', req.params.userid);

  query.run().then(approvals => {
  approvals.forEach(approval => console.log(approval));
  console.log(approvals[0].length);
  res.status(200).json(
    {
      message: "Request was processed successfully!",
      approvals: approvals[0]
    }
  );
})
})
```

The console logging on node endpoint returns a proper count value for the results being queries for. However, console logging of the same results on the Angular service code returns duplicates and the number of duplicates increase by one for every call. Example: 1st call - 2 duplicates, 2nd call - 3 duplicates, 3rd call - 3 duplicates and so on.

More information...
I am making nested subscription from my angular component. Something like below -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params
      .subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
         ....some code goes here...
         this.revenueService.GetUserInvoicesThisWeek(this.userid);
         this.currentWeekInvoicesSub = this.revenueService.GetUserInvoicesThisWeekListener()
            .subscribe((revenueInfo: Revenue[]) => {
            ....some code goes here...
            });
         this.currentDayInvoicesSub = this.revenueService.GetUserInvoicesTodayListener()
            .subscribe((todayRevenueInfo: Revenue[]) => {
            ....some code goes here...
            });
         this.approvalsService.GetUserPendingApprovals(this.userid);
         this.approvalsSub = this.approvalsService.getUserApprovalsUpdateListener()
            .subscribe((approvalsPending: any[]) => {
            ....some code goes here...
            });
         });
}
```

The last subscription is where i am facing problems. But i am pretty sure the rendered promise right after the node endpoint call is returning duplicates. Something which i mentioned in the beginning of this question.

Doubts:
What would be the root cause for these duplicates?
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are the duplicate in the array:  this.approvalsUpdated?

Comment: @Aragorn this.approvalsUpdated is an object of rxjs subject. `private approvalsUpdated = new Subject<any>();` But i believe the duplicates are actually arising before this.approvalsUpdated is being loaded. I can see the duplicates when this line - `console.log(approvals.approvals);` gets executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are subscribing everytime this function gets called, so you're making a duplicate subscription everytime you change your route.

```
GetUserPendingApprovals(userid: string) {
            let approvalsPending: any[] = [];
            this.http
              .get<{message, approvals: any}>(`/api/approvals/${userid}`)
                .subscribe(approvals => {
                  console.log(approvals.approvals);
                  approvalsPending = approvals.approvals;
                  this.approvalsUpdated.next(approvalsPending);
                  approvalsPending = [];
              });
          }
```

Subscribe in the component instead in the service to fix this issue.

```
GetUserPendingApprovals(userid: string) {

    return this.http
          .get<{message, approvals: any}>(`/api/approvals/${userid}`)

      }
```

Component ts:

```
 ngOnInit(){
   this.aprovalSub = this.approvalsService.GetUserPendingApprovals(this.userid);
    .subscribe(approvals => {
                      approvalsService.approvalsPending = approvals.approvals;
                      approvalsService.approvalsUpdated.next(approvalsPending);
                       });
}

ngOnDestroy(){
  if(this.aprovalSub !== undefined) this.aprovalSub.unsubscribe()
}
```

Clean up subscriptions when component gets destroyed or they will stay in memory and you will have subscriptions taking up memory.

Comment: Are you saying, i need to make a api call from within the component?

Comment: @user464159 ive edited my answer, so it shows more in detail what to do to fix that issue

Comment: Thank you. That worked for me. But could you please elaborate a bit more on what mistake i made and how to take care in future? Also, if you feel that this post is useful for others, please up vote my question.

Comment: So when you write a function that has a http call and you subscribe in that function to that call. Whenever you call that function you will get a new subscription added to the subscription pool and that is why you get duplicates. There are multiple ways to handle that. For me best practice is to subscribe in the component where you need that data and if possible with async pipe (it handles subing & unsubing for you). Other soluction is to use rxjs and take(1) operator, or if you are not expecting a stream, but single data chunk maybe go with toPromise and async/await